# I have wrong sql query

Tags: sql

I am studying SQL and try to work with simple db. But I have one problem with query. I have two tables department and employee.

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
(
    ID       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME     VARCHAR(14),
    LOCATION VARCHAR(13)
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
    ID         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRSTNAME  VARCHAR(10),
    LASTNAME   VARCHAR(10),
    MIDDLENAME VARCHAR(10),
    POSITION   VARCHAR(9),
    MANAGER    INTEGER,
    HIREDATE   DATE,
    SALARY     DOUBLE,
    DEPARTMENT INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT FK_DEPTNO FOREIGN KEY (DEPARTMENT) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (ID)
);
```

I need select all employees and corresponding department name if there is one. I use next query.

```
select lastname, salary, department.name as depname 
from employee, department 
where employee.department = department.id or employee.department is null
```

In result I have one employee who does not corresponding any department in db and he should have "null" in departmen area but he has departmen. I dont know why it occure.

```
                            "CLARK - 2450.0 - ACCOUNTING",
                            "MILLER - 1300.0 - ACCOUNTING",
                            "ALLEN - 1600.0 - SALES",
                            "BLAKE - 2850.0 - SALES",
                            "TURNER - 1500.0 - SALES",
                            "SMITH - 800.0 - RESEARCH",
                            "ADAMS - 1100.0 - RESEARCH",
                            "SCOTT - 3000.0 - RESEARCH",
                            "WARD - 1250.0 - SALES",
                            "KING - 5000.0 - null", in this area I have not null 
                            "MARTIN - 1250.0 - SALES",
                            "FORD - 3000.0 - RESEARCH",
                            "JONES - 2975.0 - RESEARCH",
                            "JAMES - 950.0 - SALES"
```

Please help me :) Thank you and sorry for my bad english .

Comment: Please add sample data

Comment: Could you please tell, why you avoid using LEFT JOIN? It was designed for this kind of queries

Comment: You need to use an `outer join`.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and **easier to convert to outer join** if needed

Comment: **Bad habits to kick** : [using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `JOIN` in general.  *Always*.

And in this case in particular, you want `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select e.lastname, e.salary, d.name as depname
from employee e left join
     department d
     on e.department = d.id;
```